# Can't delete content type that I created?

Tags: nodes

I am running a Drupal 6 installation and created 2 content types through the admin menu (they are not programically created). Now I want to delete them but no delete link is visible in the content type screen. I do not have any pages created with those types so I don't understand why Drupal won't let me delete them.

I have searched this site and Google but I can't find an answer. Anyone here have any ideas how to get rid of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging around, I did find that ubercart had a reference to the content type in question in one of its configuration screens. So although I didn't create any nodes of that type, the reference to that node is what was preventing me from deleting it. Once I removed the reference, the delete link appeared again.

Thanks to everyone who proposed answers as it will help someone else who might experience this problem.

Comment: If you are using "features" to configure a custom content type you might have to disable the feature in question in order to delete

Answer (score 5):

Ensure you are **user/1** and try navigating to this page

```
/admin/structure/types/manage/<content-type-name>/delete
```

replace `<content-type-name>` with the actual name of the content type

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `http://my.site.com/admin/content/node-type/<your-content-type-name-machine-name>` you should have a delete button at the bottom of the page.